# How to get any data from datagridview when I click on the row in datagridview?

Tags: c#

How can I get any data from datagridview when I click on the row in datagridview?

I tried this :

```
String x = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

It always returns a first data in datagridview.

Can anybody help?

Comment: `dataGridView1.Rows[Any_index].Cells[0].Value`

Comment: but i want to get a data, when i click on the row in datagriedview

Comment: then you should say that. the question asks `How can i get a any data`

Comment: ok, sorry about my question, do you know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set event listener to `CellClick` event:

```
dataGridView1.CellClick += DataGridView1_CellClick;
```

Handler:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    string s = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
}
```